# HTML5 - Socket.IO & Canvas

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, socket.io, sails.js

I am attempting to make a little application where multiple people can move a square around with their arrow keys with the help of Socket.IO.

For my backend I am using Sails.JS and on frontend mostly Angular.

**Backend:**

```
  var remotePlayers = [];
  var findPlayerById = {};
  var Player;

  function LocalPlayer(x, y, id) {
         this.x = x;
         this.y = y;
         this.id = id;
  }

  socket.on('new player', function(data) {
        // data = user.id;
        socket.id = data;
        LocalPlayer = new LocalPlayer(defaultX,defaultY, socket.id);

        remotePlayers.push(LocalPlayer);

        for (var i = 0; i < remotePlayers.length; i++) {
            findPlayerById[remotePlayers[i].id] = remotePlayers[i];
        };

        Player = findPlayerById[socket.id];
        console.log(Player);
        // Emit to all clients
        sails.sockets.blast('player joined', remotePlayers);
    })
```

What I am trying to do here is when the 'new player' emit is triggered, I want to save that player to my a Array(remotePlayers). Then I want to emit that Array back to the client, so the client can draw all the players.

On the client side I have a switch case where I check what key was pressed, I emit this keyValue and a userId to the Server.
Server then make sure the move is valid, does some calculations and returns the updated position of the Player.

```
 socket.on('move player', function updatePlayerPosition(data) {
        // data = Key and userId
        switch(data.key) {
            case 37:
                // Some checks here then set new value
                Player.x = Player.x - 10;

                sails.sockets.blast('player moved', remotePlayers);
                break;
            case 38:
```

Then after I have emitted 'player moved', I want my client to draw and display the updated position of the Player.

**Client:**

```
  SocketService.on('player joined', function(data) {
      // data = {x: 50, y:50, id: 'random string'}
      draw(data);
  })

  function draw(data) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDTH);

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        // data[i].x = 30
        ctx.fillStyle = 'black';
        ctx.fillRect(data[i].x, data[i].y, 20, 20);
    };
}
```

**Problem:** When I open two browsers and try to move my Player(rectangle) it always selects the same rectangle to move. If i use one browser it works, then i open up another one(2 browsers) and both browsers will then move the 2nd browsers rectangle. Does that make any sense?

Player is always the last client to join. What am I missing here? I am pretty new to this so it could be plenty I'm afraid :) Need more code? Just ask and I'll add.

Any suggestions, ideas or links are much appreciated!